# ARGV ignores # sign

Tags: ruby

Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts ARGV.inspect
```

Here is test

```
$ argvtest fixed progress bar closes #88
["fixed", "progress", "bar", "closes"]
```

How do I fix my argvtest such that I could capture `#88`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash ignores everything after the `#` sign. Call it like this:

```
$ echo foo \#bar
```

or this

```
$ echo foo '#bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the shell; # is a comment character to the shell.

You should be able to put that argument in quotes:

```
$ argvtest fixed progress bar closes "#88"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the argument in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`#88` is never sent to the script as it's the syntax for comments in most shells.

Try `\#88`